# Combining multiple sets of data to one JSON file from api calls

Tags: python, json, api, web-scraping

I need two sets of data from this website:

https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/aapl/institutional-holdings

Which include both the "Active Positions" and "New and Sold Out Positions" tables. The code i have can only provide one piece of data into a JSON:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://api.nasdaq.com/api/company/AAPL/institutional-holdings?limit=15&type=TOTAL&sortColumn=marketValue&sortOrder=DESC'

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'origin': 'https://www.nasdaq.com',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['data']['newSoldOutPositions']['rows'])

df.to_json('AAPL_institutional_positions.json')
```

This will give the output of the following (JSON):

```
{
    "positions":{
        "0":"New Positions",
        "1":"Sold Out Positions"
    },
    "holders":{
        "0":"99",
        "1":"90"
    },
    "shares":{
        "0":"37,374,118",
        "1":"4,637,465"
    }
}
```

Whereas, for the other table I am scraping, I use this code (All's I have done is change "newSoldOutPositions" to "activePositions"):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://api.nasdaq.com/api/company/AAPL/institutional-holdings?limit=15&type=TOTAL&sortColumn=marketValue&sortOrder=DESC'

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'origin': 'https://www.nasdaq.com',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['data']['activePositions']['rows'])

df.to_json('AAPL_institutional_positions.json')
```

Which gives this output (JSON):

```
{
    "positions":{
        "0":"Increased Positions",
        "1":"Decreased Positions",
        "2":"Held Positions",
        "3":"Total Institutional Shares"
    },
    "holders":{
        "0":"1,780",
        "1":"2,339",
        "2":"283",
        "3":"4,402"
    },
    "shares":{
        "0":"239,170,203",
        "1":"209,017,331",
        "2":"8,965,339,255",
        "3":"9,413,526,789"
    }
}
```

So my question being, is how can i combine the scraping to grab both sets of data and output them all in one JSON file?

Thanks

Comment: You need to decide what you want your output to look like. Since both your dictionaries have the same keys, how will you merge them? Or do you just want to pop them both in a list or as values in another dictionary?

Comment: I would like for the keys to change to fit the order inside the second JSON if possible? @PranavHosangadi

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the expected output for your two JSON objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want json data, there is no need to use pandas:

```
import requests

nasdaq_dict = {}

url = 'https://api.nasdaq.com/api/company/AAPL/institutional-holdings?limit=15&type=TOTAL&sortColumn=marketValue&sortOrder=DESC'

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'origin': 'https://www.nasdaq.com',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

nasdaq_dict['activePositions'] = r.json()['data']['activePositions']['rows']
nasdaq_dict['newSoldOutPositions'] = r.json()['data']['newSoldOutPositions']['rows']
print(nasdaq_dict)
```

Result in terminal:

```
{'activePositions': [{'positions': 'Increased Positions', 'holders': '1,795', 'shares': '200,069,709'}, {'positions': 'Decreased Positions', 'holders': '2,314', 'shares': '228,105,026'}, {'positions': 'Held Positions', 'holders': '308', 'shares': '8,976,744,094'}, {'positions': 'Total Institutional Shares', 'holders': '4,417', 'shares': '9,404,918,829'}], 'newSoldOutPositions': [{'positions': 'New Positions', 'holders': '121', 'shares': '55,857,143'}, {'positions': 'Sold Out Positions', 'holders': '73', 'shares': '8,851,038'}]}
```

Comment: Great thank you, how would i be able to save the output to a JSON file?

Comment: You would also `import json`, then do something like `with open('nasdaq_dict.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(nasdaq_dict, f)`

Comment: Thanks again, where did you get the api link from? Can you send in a link for that, as the links i'm seeing on the nasdaq website are different. @BarrythePlatipus

Comment: @kiestuthridge23 the API endpoint can be found under Dev Tools - Network tab - XHR calls.